# Date and time is not displaying even if I add Datetime?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

In this below code to display a date picker in Flutter as I press a button but nothing happens. I tried looking into the docs found noting there are no errors on how I can debug this or get to work.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart" ;
import "dart:async";
void main() {
   runApp(new MaterialApp(
     home: new Baseapp(),
   ));
}

class Baseapp extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _State createState() => new _State();
}
class _State extends State<Baseapp> {
  String _value = '';

  Future _selectDate() async {
    DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: new DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: new DateTime(2016),
        lastDate: new DateTime(2019)
    );
    if(picked != null) setState(() => _value = picked.toString());
  }
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar:  new AppBar(
        title :  new  Text("NAME HERE", style :TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow ,
      ),
      body: new Container(
      padding :   new EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            children:<Widget>[
              new Text(_value),
             new ElevatedButton(onPressed:_selectDate, child: new Text("Date")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(picked != null){
      setState(() {
        int year = picked.year;
        int mth = picked.month;
        int day = picked.day;
        _value = '${day} / ${mth} / ${year}';
      });
```

hey I figured it out XD
this particular code was missing.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your showDatePicker function, try implementing a builder, like so:

```
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(1900),
      lastDate: lastDate,
      //Implement builder here
      builder: (context, child) => child,
```

That should solve the issue.

Comment: The return type 'Widget?' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context. this is the error I get

Answer (score 0):

```
Future _selectDate() async {
DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: new DateTime.now(),
    firstDate: new DateTime(2016),
    lastDate: new DateTime(2019) //<= you used here past year but you set initial date is today so use here future year such as "lastDate: new DateTime(2019)" other wise intial date set to less than last year
```

lastDate: new DateTime(2024)
);

you used here last date in past year but you set initial date is today so use here future year such as "lastDate: new DateTime(2019)" other wise intial date set to less than last year

Comment: hey that's true, you can check out my code which I fixed, what u mentioned was also the problem,thank you